# Interactive, pannable timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

[History of HMDs timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liwyP.jpg)

Hello!

I am trying to work out how to create an interactive, pannable website modeled after this mind map style graphic. It will be part of an exhibition that includes physical artifacts from the history of head mounted displays.

Furthermore, the physical artifacts will have QR codes next to them that ideally will bring you to a specific section of this graphic that references it.

We have little time or bandwidth to make this work, so I am certainly looking for a middle ground between elegance and dev-time as far as how I implement it.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Also, we have access to an 8th Wall subscription, so I have been thinking about building it in there considering that would possibly eliminate the new tab situation that we are running into when you use a camera app to open the QR code link. If anyone has experience in this domain let me know!

We created the first version using Mira, simply creating frame views within the Miro canvas and creating QR codes from the frames sharable link, but its not the greatest implementation because each time you scan a new QR code it opens a new browser window and a pop-up appears asking you to download the Miro app.

I have little web-dev experience, and attempted to recreate this using an html/javascript canvas object, but have not made great progress. I am also unable to find a way to create links to specific coordinates or "frames" within the canvas.